# How to apply Hahn-Banach to the convex hull?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-hulls, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma 4.1.2 in [Michel Talagrand's publication from 1995 on concentration inequalities](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1995__81__73_0.pdf) (see below for the precise question statement):

---

> [image]

---

**A bit of context:** Talagrand fixes a point $x\in X$ (he uses the notation $X=\Omega$) and a subset $A\subset X$, where $X=X_1\times X_2\times\dots X_n$ is the product space of arbitrary non-empty sets $X_1,\dots, X_n$. The $\alpha_i$ and $t$ are all supposed to be positive real numbers. He defines $A_t^c$ as follows:

---

> [image]

---

**My question.** I understand why (4.1.4) implies (4.1.5). However, Talagrand says that "the converse follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem". **How does it follow from the Hahn-Banach theorem?**

---

**Note:** The problem can be slightly reformulated by saying that we want to prove that for $t>0$ and all $M\subset\{0,1\}^n$, we have that whenever $$\text{for all }\alpha\in]0,\infty[^n, \text{ there exists a } m\in M \text{ such that } \langle \alpha, m \rangle \le t\lVert \alpha\rVert_2,$$ then

$$\min_{m \in \text{Convex hull of } M} \lVert m \rVert_2 \le t.$$

In fact, if somebody can show this, then I will be able to prove the conjecture formulated by me [yesterday](https://mathoverflow.net/q/364098).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve the problem you mention at the end you can argue in this way:
$$
\min_{m \in \mathrm{conv} (M)} \|m\|_{2}=\min_{m \in \mathrm{conv} (M)} \max_{\|\alpha\|_{2}\leq 1} \langle \alpha, m\rangle = \max_{\|\alpha\|_{2}\leq 1} \min_{m \in \mathrm{Conv}(M)}\langle \alpha, m\rangle \leq  \max_{\|\alpha\|_{2}\leq 1, \alpha \in [0, \infty)^{n}} \min_{m \in M}\langle \alpha, m\rangle \leq t
$$

The only nontrivial observation was used is min-max theorem, which says that if $X, Y$ are convex compact sets, $f(x,y)$ continuous, convex in $x$ and concave in $y$ then $\min_{x \in X} \max_{y \in Y} f(x,y) = \max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X}  f(x,y)$. Choose $f(x,y)=\langle x, y\rangle$

Comment: Amazing! Can't this be used to also directly prove my conjecture [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364098/exchanging-supremum-and-minimum-with-different-constraints-for-the-convex-distan) as the last inequality seems like an equality to me if you consider the Bauer maximum principle ? (The right-hand side is just the minimum of norms over the convex hull of $M$.)

Comment: Turns out the answer is "yes, it can!". Please have a look at [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/364206/129831) which is a very small extension of your answer.